# Logistic regression negative coefficient interpretation (reciprocal of negative logistic coefficient )

Tags: r, logistic-regression, interpretation

Suppose if a dependent variable is having a disease (1) and not having a disease (0). similarly , independent variable is smoking and not smoking. here , not smoking as reference group.
Again, if logistic coefficient of smoking is - 0.3.
odd ratio = exp (-0.3) = 0.74
Can we interpret it as , reciprocal of odd ratio= 1/0.74 = 1.34 ..
Smoker have 1.34 times odd of not having disease than non smoker. or
is it " Non smoker have 1.34 times odd of having disease than smoker"
is both interpretation correct or not ? I am just confused.

Comment: Can you please share some information: (a) how is the smoking variable encoded? Zero for not smoking? (b) Is there only one independent variable in the model or is (non-)smoking just the one of interest, here. But there are more?

Comment: for smoking ( smoker = 1, and non-smoker = 0) . Yes for the model, this variable is only of interest.